# Java: How to close loop with sentinel after first input (when using multiple inputs)

Tags: java, loops, sentinel

I have spent hours trying to figure this out, so I apologize if it's an easy fix.

I would like to make this program more user-friendly. Everything works currently, but the sentinel requires I enter "0" for both miles drive and gas used. I would like the sentinel to end the program after I enter the "0" for miles only. Is this possible?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Mileage
```

{

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{   //initialization
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int miles = -1, gallons = -1,
            totalMiles = 0, totalGallons = 0;
    double average, runningAverage;
    //while loop with sentinel controlled repetition
    while (miles != 0 && gallons != 0)
    {   //get miles 
        System.out.println("Enter the amount of miles driven. (0 to exit)");
        miles = sc.nextInt();
        //get gallons
        System.out.println("Enter the amount of gallons used. (0 to exit)");
        gallons = sc.nextInt();
        //calc average
        average = (double) miles / gallons;

        //calc running average
        totalMiles += miles;
        totalGallons += gallons;
        runningAverage = (double) totalMiles / totalGallons;

        //output average only if values were entered, by using if statement
        if (miles != 0 && gallons != 0)
        {
            System.out.printf("Miles per gallon for this trip is %.1f%n", average);

            System.out.printf("Running average miles per gallon is %.1f%n", runningAverage);
        }
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do:

```
miles = sc.nextInt();
```

you can make a check for exit the program like:

```
if(miles==0){
    System.exit(0);
}
```

just before:

```
System.out.println("Enter the amount of gallons used. (0 to exit)");
```

Comment: Holy crap. I knew it must be an easy fix, which is why I wasn't finding anything for it. Thank you so much!

Comment: Sometimes the easiest thing despair. Hope it helps cya!

Answer (score 0):

*I would like the sentinel to end the program after I enter the "0" for miles only.*

If I understand what you're asking for, just change

```
while (miles != 0 && gallons != 0)
```

to

```
while (miles != 0)
```

**and**

```
System.out.println("Enter the amount of gallons used. (0 to exit)");
```

to

```
System.out.println("Enter the amount of gallons used.");
```

You may find it more convenient to terminate the loop on `0` miles. Like,

```
miles = sc.nextInt();
if (miles == 0) {
    break;
}
```

Otherwise, it's going to prompt for `gallons` again.

Comment: The second part of your comment is exactly what I was after. I knew there had to be an easy way, I just couldn't find it. Thank you so much!